# What parameters does invoke() method accept?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 20.2. I saw the following line of code `apex.region( "myGridRegion" ).widget().interactiveGrid( "getActions" ).invoke( "selection-add-row" );` in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/region.html#widget). It passes `selection-add-row` to `invoke()` method as a parameter. I need to know what other parameters does `invoke()` accept? And how to know them? Is there a way to know what parameters a method accepts i.e writing something in the browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write:

```js
apex.region( "myGridRegion" ).widget().interactiveGrid( "getActions" )
```

as

```js
apex.region( "myGridRegion" ).call( "getActions" )
```

This should return an Actions object. From here you can call `list()` to get a list of all actions:

```js
apex.region( "myGridRegion" ).call( "getActions" ).list()
```

Answer (score 1):

The "selection-add-row" is an "Action" in the "interactiveGrid" widget. The available actions are documented in the widget [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. That answered my question. But is there any way to figure out what parameters a method takes, in case I came across one that is not documented?

Comment: You could go through the source code, that is readable in a js file. But I have not done this myself.

Comment: Pls mark the question as answered (you upvoted it instead)